# breacrumb directive for angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angular.js, require.js

This is a simple directive that creates breadcrumbs on the fly for Angular.js pages using angular-ui-router

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var app, loaded;

  loaded = false;

  app = angular.module('uiBreadcrumbs', ['ui.router', 'ngSanitize']);

  app.directive('uiBreadcrumb', ['$state', '$rootScope', function($state, $rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var abstract;
        attrs.abstract = attrs.abstract ? attrs.abstract : false;
        abstract = JSON.parse(attrs.abstract);

        /*
         * watch for trasition success events
         * on state change success load breadcrumbs
         */
        $rootScope.$on('updateBreadCrumbs', function(event, trans) {
          var i, parentStates, stateArray;
          loaded = true;
          scope.$breadcrumbs = [];
          stateArray = [];
          parentStates = [];

          /*
           * gets all states
           */
          for (i in $state.$current.includes) {
            stateArray.push(i);
          }

          /*
           * get parent state details
           */
          for (i in stateArray) {
            if (stateArray[i] !== '') {
              if ($state.get(stateArray[i]).$$state().parent.self.name !== '') {
                parentStates.push($state.get(stateArray[i]).$$state().parent.self);
              }
            }
          }

          /*
           * if abstract is false
           * removes abstract states from breadcrumbs
           */
          if (!abstract) {
            for (i in parentStates) {
              if (!parentStates[i].abstract) {
                scope.$breadcrumbs.push(parentStates[i]);
              }
            }
          } else {
            scope.$breadcrumbs = parentStates;
          }

          /*
           * add current state to breadcrumbs
           */
          scope.$breadcrumbs.push($state.current);
        });
      },
      template: '<ol class="breadcrumb">' + '  <li ng-repeat="data in $breadcrumbs"><a ui-sref="{{data.abstract || data.name}}" ng-class="{\'disabled\': data.abstract}">{{data.label || data.name}}</a></li>' + '</ol>'
    };
  }]);

  app.run(['$rootScope', '$transitions', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $transitions, $timeout) {
    return $transitions.onSuccess({}, function(trans) {
      if (loaded) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $rootScope.$emit('updateBreadCrumbs', trans);
        }, 0);
      } else {
        $timeout(function() {
          $rootScope.$emit('updateBreadCrumbs', trans);
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
  }]);

}).call(this);
```

This directive creates breadcrumbs dynamically on page load and on any successful state change.

The directive works well with normal angular.js applications but does not work well with require.js apps. so I came up with a temporary solution that sets a loaded state. when the loaded state is false i.e., at page load the timeout is set for 1000 ms once the function is executed then the loaded state is set to true. then on the next time update happens with less time interval. I am not sure of things that I miss for require.js applications to load this properly.

Comment: Could whoever voted to close this as "broken code" please explain why they consider it broken? I can't see it ...

Comment: @Vogel612 I didn't vote, but the very `can someone check this code` implies that it is not ready for the review.

Comment: @vnp. I checked this code and it is working fine. but I am not sure that what I did falls under the best practices etc., especially about the `run block` in the code. If the statement you mentioned gives a wrong impression. Can I edit the question?

Comment: @SibiRaj Sure you can and shall. This site only review the code which works perfectly to the best of the asker's knowledge.